# Load object which extends trait with Scala Relfection

Tags: scala, reflection

Following example:

```
trait Config {
  val values: Map[String, String]
  def get(id: String): Option[String] = values.get(id)
}

object Config {
  def apply(): Config = {
    // Here I need a way to return the 'LocalConfig' object
  }
}

object LocalConfig extends Config {
  override val values: Map[String, String] = Map("ID" -> "Value")
}

println(Config().get("ID")) // => "Value"
```

Is there any way to return the `LocalConfig` object form the `apply` dynamically, so it would work independently how the object `LocalConfig` is named?

Thank you

Comment: If you have enough control over code to make sure there is exactly one such object, you likely have enough control to name it as desired.

Comment: So you essentially want to enumerate all subclasses of a given trait and then pick one of them based on some logic?

Comment: Hi Eugene: yes, this is what I like to do.